# Using Multiple Base URLs and Multiple Object Managers (RestKit)

Tags: ios, api, restkit

I'm trying to use two API's in an iOS app.

I'm using RestKit and following their guide per this article: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Using-Multiple-Base-URLs-(and-Multiple-Object-Managers)

What do I do instead of the `retain` in this code since its no longer an option?

**AppDelegate.m**

```
RKObjectManager *flickrManager = 
        [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:flickrBaseUrl]; // <-- shared singleton
RKObjectManager *foursquareManager = 
        [[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:foursquareBaseUrl] retain]; // <-- you must retain every other instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store all of the object managers somewhere. If using ARC you don't retain, you want to store in an array / dictionary (key with the URL perhaps) / properties (strong).

In the example code you show, the first object manager isn't retained because RestKit holds one reference for you (the singleton). Generally, when using multiple object managers you want to ignore the singleton storage and manage all of the object manager references yourself.

I would recommend using a data controller which hides the object manager properties internally and instead exposes an API based on your data model objects. Internally, it can choose the appropriate object manager for each request it receives.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have a link to anything on your third paragraph on a how-to?  Conceptually I understand where you're going with it, but have never done it-

Comment: Currently I have the Models already set up.  And then I also have a View Controller.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about abstracting the view controllers away from the RestKit classes. So the view controller simply wants to get some data or save some data. A data controller provides an interface in those terms, and it makes the RestKit requests to action the requests. There is no documentation on that as such (that I'm aware of).

Comment: So just specifically speaking of this AppDelegate, do I just remove the `retain` from the code?

Comment: Remove the retain, yes, but then you need something like `self.foursquareManager = foursquareManager;` so that the instance is retained (by the strong property).

Comment: When I do that I get an error `Property foursquareManager not found on object of type AppDelegate`.  What am I missing there?

Comment: The property ;-) -- and that's why you should have a data controller to own that responsibility. The AppDelegate is not the correct place to put this responsibility.

Comment: Got it.  So move this code into the `ViewController` and make the property `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *foursquareArray;` ?

Comment: Which the line would then be `self.foursquareArray = foursquareManager`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48774/discussion-between-wain-and-reez)